# Python Django Mezzanine Models Import

Tags: python, django, content-management-system, mezzanine

```
from django.db import models
from mezzanine.pages.models import Page

# The members of Page will be inherited by the Author model, such
# as title, slug, etc. For authors we can use the title field to
# store the author's name. For our model definition, we just add
# any extra fields that aren't part of the Page model, in this
# case, date of birth.

class Author(Page):
    dob = models.DateField("Date of birth")

class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey("Author")
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to="authors")
```

So does Book also inherits properties of Page?  So it means any property or method of Page is accessible from the above code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to user foreign key relationship if you want to extend a model. You can use a one-to-one relationship to a model containing the fields for additional information. For example:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    page = models.OneToOneField(Page)
    dob = models.DateField("Date of birth")
```

you can access the related information using Django’s standard related model conventions:

```
a = Author.objects.get(...) 
name = a.page.title # author's name is stored in Page.title field
```